# Unable to start Marklogic service on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, marklogic

I have connected to an AWS instance which was set up for MarkLogic using the AWS Systems Manager. I am trying to start the MarkLogic Server, but I am receiving the following error response:

```
Set configuration: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.amzn2.0.1.x86_64"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_MDB_TYPE=""
Set configuration: AWS_REGION="ap-southeast-2"
Set configuration: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="ap-southeast-2"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_ZONE="ap-southeast-2a"
Initialize Configuration.
AWS Region: ap-southeast-2, ZONE: ap-southeast-2a. INSTANCE: i-08c0992c858711a67
Instance is not managed
Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/nvme1n1
Volume /dev/sdf has failed to attach - aborting

Warning: ec2-startup did not complete successfully
Check the error logs for details

Starting MarkLogic:                                        [FAILED]
```

This was the output on the log for mlcmd:

```
"2020-08-17 02:10:26,821 0     INFO  [main] shell.Shell - xmlsh initialize
"2020-08-17 02:10:26,952 131   INFO  [main] builtin.log - loading init.xsh
"2020-08-17 02:10:27,102 281   INFO  [main] builtin.log - initializing mlcmd
"2020-08-17 02:10:27,103 282   INFO  [main] builtin.log - loading /var/local/mlcmd.conf
"2020-08-17 02:10:27,297 476   TRACE [main] mlcmd.trace - init-config: exit-status: 1 args: Not loading mdb functions - not a managed cluster
"2020-08-17 02:10:27,299 478   TRACE [main] mlcmd.trace - complete init.xsh: exit-status: 1 args:
"2020-08-17 02:10:27,299 478   INFO  [main] builtin.log - runing init-config.xsh
"2020-08-17 02:10:27,942 0     INFO  [main] shell.Shell - xmlsh initialize
"2020-08-17 02:10:28,042 100   INFO  [main] builtin.log - loading init.xsh
"2020-08-17 02:10:28,173 231   INFO  [main] builtin.log - initializing mlcmd
"2020-08-17 02:10:28,174 232   INFO  [main] builtin.log - loading /var/local/mlcmd.conf
"2020-08-17 02:10:28,387 445   TRACE [main] mlcmd.trace - ec2-startup: exit-status: 1 args: Not loading mdb functions - not a managed cluster
"2020-08-17 02:10:28,389 447   TRACE [main] mlcmd.trace - complete init.xsh: exit-status: 1 args:
```

How do I resolve this issue?

If there is more required information, do let me know and I will try to get it

Comment: Seems a EBS volume failed to get attached. Are you running the instance in same AZ as where the volume is located?

Comment: How would I check for the location of the volume?

Comment: In the EC2 console you can find `Volumes` menu and then you can check the volumes and their Availability Zones.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are attempting to start a self-managed instance/cluster, while the Managed Cluster feature has not been disabled.

The [MarkLogic Managed Cluster](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/overview#id_31071) feature is the recommended way to deploy a MarkLogic Cluster on AWS so it is enabled by default. Managed clusters are meant to be deployed using the [MarkLogic CloudFormation Templates](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws/).

[Deploying MarkLogic on EC2 Using CloudFormation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/CloudFormation)

The Managed Cluster feature reduces the amount of work necessary to setup the initial cluster, and creates an Auto Scaling Group that will automatically re-launch an instance that gets terminated, and when MarkLogic starts on the new instance, it will remount the associated EBS data drive.

[CloudFormation Template Overview](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/CloudFormation#id_19554)

If you wish to have a self-managed cluster, then you will need to create an `/etc/marklogic.conf` file to disable the feature at startup.

[AWS Configuration Variables](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/CloudFormation)

[Best Practice Editing MarkLogic Server Environment Variables](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/best-practice-editing-marklogic-server-environment-variables)

I would recommend reviewing the following guide, as it details using both the Managed Cluster feature, as well as self-managed clusters.

[MarkLogic Server on Amazon Web Services (AWS) Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2)